# Placement of satellites

Tags: launch, artificial-satellite, rockets

Within what degree of accuracy can a satellite be placed into orbit around earth, or any object for that matter?

Is it placed to within a few meters or rather a few kilometers?

Comment: This is hard to answer in a general sense, like you worded the question, since it depends on a multitude of interactive forces involved and precision of craft's own hardware. And if you had in mind formation flying, then all these variables translate to even more units in the whole satellite constellation. It has been shown that two satellites can continue to operate even if they unwittingly attached to each other, so this distance would be 0. Do you have any specific regions with specific requirements in mind? Note though, we already have questions about e.g. GEO slot assignment and similar.

Comment: @TidalWave, sorry if the question was unclear. I did not mean how close different satellites can be placed together, I rather meant how close can a satellite be placed to it's intended final position in space. Does this make my question more clear?

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] to clarify, yes. Seems you're asking about the precision of launching satellites into their designated target orbits using upper stages, and not their own ability to precision stationkeep when in their designated slot using own thrusters? An example of what you had in mind could help avoid confusion over what you're asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to give you an idea, here's the accuracy numbers from the [Falcon 9](http://decadal.gsfc.nasa.gov/pace-201206mdl/Launch%20Vehicle%20Information/Falcon9UsersGuide_2009.pdf). Each rocket has it's own uncertainty, but the F9 is pretty representative.

Low Earth Orbit

- Perigee ± 10 km
- Apogee ± 10 km
- Inclination ± 0.1 deg
- Right Ascension of Ascending Node ± 0.15 deg

Geosynchronous Transfer Orbit

- Perigee ± 7.4 km
- Apogee ± 130 km
- Inclination ± 0.1 deg
- Right Ascension of Ascending Node ± 0.75 deg
- Argument of Perigee ± 0.3 deg

These are the parameters that really count for orbits. They could represent a fairly large uncertainty in the predicted path.

Comment: Thank you @PearsonArtPhoto. This is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Note that an orbit that is exactly on spec today could be off spec tomorrow, unless corrections are continuously made. Atmospheric drag, light pressure, micrometeoroid impact, the non-spherical earth are only a few possible perturbing factors...